# How to get all active video devices that are currently attach?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediadevices

I am trying to get all active video devices. But instead of that, I am receiving all the video devices that were attached previously. My goal is to get only video devices that are currently attach and ready for use.

I tried using navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(); to get all active device but instead of that I received a lot of devices that are not active.

```
           navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
                .then(function(devices) {
                    devices.forEach(function (device) {
                        if (device.kind === "videoinput") {
                                alert(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
                                " id = " + device.deviceId);
                        }
                  });
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                  alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerateDevices returns all devices that are (according to the operating system) attached to the system (see [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadevices-enumeratedevices))

If you want to know which devices are currently used (by the same web page) you'll have to keep track of this yourself when getUserMedia resolves.

Comment: thank you for your answer! The problem is that it gives me even if the device is detached from the system, and I need to get only the devices that are attached currently (at the moment).

Comment: that sounds like a bug, you might want to file one in the respective bugtracker [found here](https://webrtc.org/bugs/)